# Reference a range adding formulas with google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I think this is probably a basic issue, but I can't find the answer after trying hard.
Both sheets are in the same workbook.

In Sheet 'MER' I want to place a formula to reference cells in Sheet 'AVL"

The first cell I want the script to place the formula is in B7 then again every 26th cell below, so B33, B59 and so on.

I'm struggling as the script I'm using only picks up a single cell which is C3 in sheet 'AVL'. I want the script to go to C3, C4, C5, C6 etc. so in

Sheet 'MER'

```
    B7=AVL!C3
    B33=AVL!C4
    B59=AVL!C5
```

And continue onwards. Here's the script I have, it just needs a bit of adjustment on the setFormula part...

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
    sheet.getRange(7 + 26*k, 2).setFormula('=AVL!C3 ');
  }
}
```

I've tried countless alterations ,+ 1' etc, but nothing works for me, and I can't find the answer via internet searches.

Any help here greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have not worked on Google Scripts but basic concepts are applicable generally. You are keeping ~setFormula('=AVL!C3 ');~ fixed so it will not vary. See example for Excel VBA. It increments an integer j and thus formula becomes variable ~Sub test2()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
j = 2
For i = 2 To 10
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=A" & j
j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
~

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's all good now. Thanks again.

Comment: Should I put this as answer which you may accept. SO way of saying thanks is by accepting as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it sucks answering a question I posted, but with some help from a script master, this script did the job perfectly...

```
function setFormulas() {

  var sheet, startRow, i; 
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  startRow = 7;
  i = 3;
  while(startRow < 5181) {
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 2).setFormula('=AVL!C' + i);
    i++;
    startRow += 26;
  }
}
```